# exchanged momentum in Compton scattering

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, scattering-cross-section

I am trying to resolve a confusion regarding scattering kinematics. I am considering Compton scattering, i.e. a photon with four-momentum $k$ scatters on an electron with four-momentum $p$, the final states are $p^\prime$ and $k^\prime$. There are two channels: the s-channel where a photon is first absorbed and later emitted, and the exchanged electron carries energy $(p+k)^2$. And the u-channel where a photon is first emitted and then absorbed, and the exchanged energy is $(p-k^\prime)^2$. Using that the external legs are on-shell I find in the first case case (say $m=0$)
\begin{equation}
(p+k)^2=2p\cdot k=2|\boldsymbol{p}|\,|\boldsymbol{q}|(1-cos\theta)
\end{equation}
and similarly in the second case
\begin{equation}
(p-k^\prime)^2=2p\cdot k^\prime=-2|\boldsymbol{p}|\,|\boldsymbol{k}^\prime|(1-cos\theta_2)
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ and $\theta_2$ are the angles in between $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{q}$ and $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{k}^\prime$ respectively. 
It seems to me that in the first case the transferred momentum is time-like and in the second case it is space-like. At least in electron-electron scattering the exchanged momentum of the virtual photon is $\textit{always}$ space-like (in both, the t and u channel), time-like momenta correspond to pair processes. Is this not true for Compton scattering? Also, there is an interference contribution for $s$ and $u$ channels, which to me seems to imply that both channels are non-zero for either space-like or time-like exchanged momenta.
I'm grateful for any input that helps me resolve my confusion. Thanks alot!